# How to launch a windows application via procdump which has commnad line args?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, procdump

I have a C++ application for windows which takes command line args.

How do I use `procdump` to launch the application with those args?

I tried :

```
> procdump64.exe -ma -x c:\dumps "C:\ProgramData\someapp.exe arg"

> procdump64.exe -ma -x c:\dumps 'C:\ProgramData\someapp.exe "arg"'
```

but both failed saying :

```
Error launching 'C:\ProgramData\someapp.exe:
The system cannot find the file specified. (0x00000002, 2)
```

But, if I run the app explicitly it runs fine.

this works :

```
> C:\ProgramData\someapp.exe "arg"
```

I didn't find anything on google about how to do this with `procdump`. I'm open to any other fairly simple-to-setup CLI if `procdump` can't do it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note the unbalanced single quote in your error message. In case you're using cmd.exe to launch this command, be aware that quoting and escaping arguments is kind-of strange there. BTW: It would help if you provide a list with the commands you tried and the error you received. From your two, I'm missing the one that doesn't try to do funny stuff with quotes at all. Also, maybe, procdump honors the Unix way of separating options from arguments with a `--`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks for the direction! it helped. I posted an answer with the command which works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [@Ulrich Eckhardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968182/ulrich-eckhardt) !
His comment pointed me to the direction where the following worked *without trying to do funny stuff with quotes* :

```
 procdump64.exe -ma -x c:\dumps C:\ProgramData\someapp.exe "arg"
```

**PS :** I was indeed running `procdump` from cmd.